# SQL Server 2008 - Update field to add a space ' ' after 3rd character

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called WellKnown with records as follows:-

```
ReferenceNo  PlaceName
-----------  ----------------------------------
1860         ALDGATE STN
1861         ALEXANDRA PALACE STN
1862         ALL SAINTS STN
1863         ALPERTON STN
```

Basically I want to UPDATE the WellKnown table and SET PlaceName so it has a space after the 3rd character. So the result would be:-

```
ReferenceNo  PlaceName
-----------  ----------------------------------
1860         ALD GATE STN
1861         ALE XANDRA PALACE STN
1862         ALL SAINTS STN
1863         ALP ERTON STN
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever query you use, it looks like you want it to NOT add another space when there is already one there. Thus the `WHERE` clause below:

```
UPDATE dbo.WellKnown
SET PlaceName = Stuff(PlaceName, 4, 0, ' ')
WHERE Substring(PlaceName, 4, 1) <> ' '
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4727/1)

The [Stuff function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) adds and removes characters from a string at the same time. In this case, in the `PlaceName` column, we want to add characters starting at character `4`, we want to remove `0` characters, and we want to insert a single space, `' '`. The `WHERE` clause restricts the `UPDATE` to only those rows where the fourth character is not already a space.

Answer (score 1):

Use [STUFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
update wellknown
set placename = stuff(placename, 4, 0, ' ')
```

Comment: I removed the first query.